# How to open a file in other window in the middle of function run?

Tags: find-file, async

I use notmuch to read emails.
I've configured `notmuch` to call `offlineimap` via `pre-new` hook.
When I press `G` to refresh my `notmuch` buffer, I want emacs to open my offlineimap log file in another window so I can see the sync process in real time.
Here's is what I've done:

```
(use-package notmuch
  :bind
  (:map notmuch-hello-mode-map
   ("G" . (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (find-file-other-window "~/Maildir/.notmuch/hooks/offlineimap.log")
            (notmuch-poll-and-refresh-this-buffer)))))
```

Problem with this is, emacs would only open the log file **after** sync is done.
How do I make emacs open the log file **before** notmuch and offlineimap action?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You may be interested in having a look at the asynchronous section of the manual -- perhaps there is something there that might suit your needs:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html  You have written the question is such a way that whoever answers it would probably need to install a lot of packages and utilities to be able to test and debug any answer, and then to tweak the answer and/or address follow-up questions.  Consider creating a minimal working example that does not require the installation of lots of packages and external utilities.

Comment: Is that because no redipslay is triggered between the two calls? If so, you might add a `(sit-for 0)` in between. But it's more likely that the refresh function is synchronous and so  emacs is "frozen" until it is done. In fact, [this](https://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2020/029571.html) seems to say as much, but it also provides a patch to make it asynchronous. Whether that's enough, I don't know, but I would guess not: you still need to tail the logfile which would probably  require a bit more work.

Comment: @NickD adding `(sit-for 0)` does fix **the** problem. Thank you so much. Now a new problem is that the other window wouldn't `auto-revert ` until function run is complete. Guess this is not as easy as I thought it would be. Maybe i'll settle with using a terminal to tail my log file.

Comment: That's the problem that @lawlist  and I mentioned: emacs is inherently single-threaded, so if it is busy doing something, then it cannot do something else at the same time. In some cases, the async mechanism can help do the long-running "thing" in a different process (while monitoring that process) so that emacs can continue being responsive in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lawlist's suggestion, I've ended up with this:

```
(use-package notmuch
  :bind
  (("G" . (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (find-file-other-window "~/Maildir/.notmuch/hooks/offlineimap.log")
            (start-process "notmuch" "notmuch" "notmuch" "new")))))
```

since  `(notmuch-poll-and-refresh-this-buffer)` is essentially just calling the external `notmuch` program and updates the current buffer, I decided to call `notmuch` myself. The drawback of this is I'll need to press `g` to update the `notmuch` buffer once after the external program finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function that logs into a buffer and also updates `notmuch` buffers:

```lisp
(setq-default notmuch-new-buffer "*notmuch-new*")

(defun my/notmuch-new ()
  """Update mail."""
  (interactive)
  (my/notmuch-new-prepare-buffer)
  (let ((process (my/notmuch-new-process)))
    (set-process-sentinel process 'my/notmuch-new-sentinel)))

(defun my/notmuch-new-prepare-buffer ()
  (switch-to-buffer notmuch-new-buffer)
  (erase-buffer)
  (insert "Updating mail...")
  (newline))

(defun my/notmuch-new-process ()
  (start-process "notmuch" notmuch-new-buffer "notmuch" "new"))

(defun my/notmuch-new-sentinel (process event)
  (notmuch-refresh-all-buffers))
```